# Как Заменить выделенный текст на html код?

Tags: javascript

```
// выделенный текст
sel = window.getSelection();

// если выделена не пустота
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    // удалит выделенный тект
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
}
```

Это заменит выделенный текст на текст, а как заменить выделенный текст на html? Т.е. мне нужно вставить между выделенным текстом теги, я предполагаю заменить полностью текст на свой html, но если можно, то вставил бы теги между тектом, как например surroundContents(), но этот метод не подходит, т.к. заменяет теги родителей, а мне нужно вставить новые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '**' + document.getSelection().toString() + '**');